# How to do sparql query to get provenance data in DBpedia?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

I want to get provenance data in [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and here's the sample query:

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?novel
WHERE {
?novel rdf:type dbo:Novel
} LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

This query returns list of novels' resource. How can I get provenance data for each resource, if it's possible?

For example [In Ballast to the White Sea](http://dbpedia.org/resource/In_Ballast_to_the_White_Sea) originated from Source A, Source A originated from Source B, Source B is originated from Source C, and so on.

Comment: By "source" you mean scientific papers, books, ... ? Or another rdf store that could be linked to dbpedia?

Comment: What sort of provenance information?  When you're looking at http://dbpedia.org/page/In_Ballast_to_the_White_Sea, you're seeing all the triples that DBpedia has about that novel.  If that contains the provenance you're looking for, then you can query it with SPARQL.  Otherwise, you'll have to get information from someplace else.

Comment: What is the "source" of the DBpedia resource of your example? The Wikipedia page? then use `http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#wasDerivedFrom` to get the page with revision number or `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/isPrimaryTopicOf` without revision. Otherwise, what would be "source B" of "source A" as you mentioned when looking again at your example resource?

Comment: Yeah by "source" i mean anything it could be papers, books or something linked to that resource. I see so it looks like i have to find the information from another source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use current provenance data existing in the dataset which is declared by `prov:wasDerivedFrom` property. It gives info about the source(wikipedia page) triples are extracted from. So you can pose such a query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX prov: <https://www.w3.org/ns/prov#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?novel ?prov
WHERE {
  ?novel rdf:type dbo:Novel.
  ?novel prov:wasDerivedFrom ?prov
} LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```